# How can I get over 401 Error returns on Poloniex new V2API?

Tags: dart, poloniex

on Dart i try to reach AUth https. However i got 401 error. I followed every single instructions on api document. Signature is correct, payload is correct.. but i got 401 error.. Could you please help about this issue? Is any body using Dart on Poloniex V2 api before?

Here is the Instruction that i followed

[Poloniex V2 Auth docs](https://docs.poloniex.com/#authentication)

Thanks

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:crypto/crypto.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

const String poloniexPrivateApiKey = "xxxxxxxxxx";
const String poloniexPrivateSecretKey =  "xxxxxxxx";


const String url = "https://api.poloniex.com";
const String publicApiUrl = "https://poloniex.com/public";

class PoloniexApiClient {
  static String v2Accounts = "/accounts";
  static String v2Orders = "/orders";
  static String v2Markets = "/markets";

  String apiKey;
  String secretKey;
  String host;

  PoloniexApiClient({this.apiKey = poloniexPrivateApiKey, this.secretKey = poloniexPrivateSecretKey, this.host = url});
  Future accounts() async {
    try {
      Map<String, dynamic> map = {};

      var response = await PoloniexSignatureHelper.generateResponse(apiKey, secretKey, host, v2Accounts, map);
      debugPrint("accountResponse: ${response.toString()}");
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint(e.toString());
    }
  }
}

class PoloniexSignatureHelper {
  static String contentType = "Content-Type";
  static String jsonType = "application/json";
  static String requestMethodGet = "GET";
  static String requestMethodPost = "POST";
  static String requestMethodDelete = "DELETE";
  static String headerTimeStamp = "signTimestamp";
  static String headerKey = "key";
  static String headerSignMethod = "signatureMethod";
  static String headerSignVersion = "signatureVersion";
  static String headerSignature = "signature";
  static String signatureMethodValue = "HmacSHA256";
  static String signatureVersionValue = "2";

  static Future<String> generateResponse(String apiKey, secretKey, host, path, Map<String, dynamic> paramMap) async {
    String timestamp = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString();

    String payload = generateSignatureRequestString(requestMethodGet, path, timestamp, paramMap);
    print(payload);

    String signature = generateSignature(secretKey, payload);
    print(signature);

    String response = await executeRequest(host, path, apiKey, timestamp, signature, paramMap);
    print(response);
    return response;
  }

  static String generateSignatureRequestString(String method, path, timestamp, Map<String, dynamic> paramMap) {
    var sortedParamMap = sortMapASCII(paramMap, timestamp);

    var encoded;
    if (method == requestMethodGet) {
      encoded = sortedParamMap.keys
          .map((key) => "${Uri.encodeComponent(key)}=${Uri.encodeComponent(paramMap[key].toString())}")
          .join("&");
    } else {
      sortedParamMap.remove(headerTimeStamp);
      var requestBody = jsonEncode(sortedParamMap); 
      encoded = "requestBody=$requestBody&signTimestamp=$timestamp"; 
    }

    var requestString = method + "\n" + path + "\n" + encoded;

    return requestString;
  }

  static String generateSignature(String secretKey, String requestString) {
    final keyBytes = base64Decode(secretKey);
    final dataBytes = utf8.encode(requestString);

    final hMacBytes = Hmac(sha256, keyBytes).convert(dataBytes).bytes;
    final hMacBase64 = base64Encode(hMacBytes);
    var sign = hMacBase64;

    return sign;
  }

  static Future<String> executeRequest(
      String host, path, apiKey, timestamp, signature, Map<String, dynamic> paramMap) async {
    String url = host + path;

    if (paramMap.isNotEmpty && paramMap.length > 0) {
      var queryStringBuffer = "?";
      paramMap.forEach((key, value) {
        queryStringBuffer = queryStringBuffer + key + "=" + value.toString() + "&";
      });

      String queryString = queryStringBuffer.substring(0, queryStringBuffer.length - 1);
      url = url + queryString;
    }

    print(url);

    Map<String, String> _headers = {
      // contentType: jsonType,
      // contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      headerKey: apiKey,
      headerSignMethod: signatureMethodValue,
      headerSignVersion: signatureVersionValue,
      headerTimeStamp: timestamp,
      headerSignature: signature
    };

    var result;
    try {
      var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url), headers: _headers);
      // if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      //   String data = response.body;
      //   result = data;
      // }

      result = response.statusCode.toString(); // return 401??
    } catch (e) {
      result = e.toString();
    }

    return result;
  }

  static Map<String, dynamic> sortMapASCII(Map<String, dynamic> paramMap, timestamp) {
    paramMap.addAll({headerTimeStamp: timestamp});
    var paramKeys = paramMap.keys.map((key) => "$key").toList();
    paramKeys.sort(((a, b) => a.compareTo(b)));

    Map<String, dynamic> sortedParamMap = {};
    paramKeys.forEach((key) => sortedParamMap.addAll({"$key": "${paramMap[key]}"}));
    print(sortedParamMap);
    return sortedParamMap;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone has problems with PHP and 401 error, You should remember to output the data as raw binary data before encoding to base64 by switching `$binary` `bool` to `true` inside `hash_hmac` function. I spent hours on this until I found the problem. I hope this answer helps.

Here's how :

```
<?php
    base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256',$request_string,$secret,true)) // *true is important
?>
```

To this day, 11.25.2023, there is no mention in the **Poloneix docs** about outputting the data as raw binary data when hashing the data. I hope they add the description.